# Is there a way to create a Python script on Google Cloud Function that Downloads a file from a Bucket to your local computer?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

Currently, I know of two ways to download a file from a bucket to your computer
1)  Manually go to the bucket and clicking download
2)  Use gsutil

Is there a way to do this in a program in Google Cloud Functions?  You can't execute gsutil in a Python script.  I also tried this:

```
with open("C:\", "wb") as file_obj:
    blob.download_to_file(file_obj)
```

but I believe that looks for a directory on Google Cloud.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using is for downloading the files from your local machine, this is covered in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python), however, as you mention this would look for the local file in the machine executing the Cloud Function.

I would suggest you to create a cron to download the files to your local instance through gsutil, doing this through a Cloud Function is not going to be possible.

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if this is possible through Firebase?

Comment: No, you would not be able to do this through Firebase due to the same reasons. It's better to go with the gsutil to copy files to your local instance.

Comment: Thanks.  My current planned workaround is just to create a download link that goes directly to the cloud bucket.  Paste the link into the website.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly achieve what you want. Cloud Function must be able to reach your local computer for copying the file on it.

The common way for sending file to a computer is to use FTP protocol. So install a FTP server on your computer and to set up your function for reading into your bucket and then send the file to your FTP server (you have to get your public IP, be sure that the firewall rules/routers are configured for this,...). It's not the easiest way.

A gsutil with a [rsync](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) command work perfectly. Use a planned task on Windows if you want to cron this.